# window.close(), self.close() not working on mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript

I want to close window on logout. I have used

- `window.close()`,
- `self.close()`,
- `var win = window.open("","_self"); win.close();`
- `window.parent.close();`

These all above i have used that all work in IE but in Mozilla Firefox not working.

Please give me solution for that.

Thanks.

Comment: And why do you want to close my window?

Answer (score 12):

I tried to review all topics about window.close() and have found that:
IE/Chrome/Safari(?) accept closure if we open something on _self, so generally

> top.open('','_self',''); top.close();

does the work.
FF (r 19 when writing this) is more strict about this and somehow forbids any probe like above. The good answer was found in related thread, that user must manually allow FF to have solution above working

> about.config -> dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows = true;

### I was quite desperated, as Customer requested window closure on completed operation.

Big bravo to FF dev team. This is exactly how it should work; pity only is that is hard to find it.

Pawel.

Answer (score 7):

I have found that ***Firefox can only use window.close()*** when script has been called to open that window in the first place.

Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.close) for more info.

So if you didn't use a script to open that window, it can't be done.

Comment: @gowri My requirement would need to close and open the window from different JS files. Then how do I do it???

Comment: what you mean "different JS files" is it external file? What is the problem with Pawel answer. What you tried, what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ive been using something like this:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" >
function ddd() {

netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");

window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow','width=400,height=200');
window.close();
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<input type= "button" name="new" value="New Window" onClick="ddd()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that they are working on Chrome Kiosk ( Fullscreen ) mode. Tried successfully. Up to 19 as of now.

Answer (score 0):

**Working 100 %  for me**

In Mozilla by default the "dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows" value which controls the Java Script close window is set to "false". In order to fix this issue change this value to "true"

Location of the File:

C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\greprefs\all.js

change "dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows" from "false" to "true"

Example:

Default value

pref("dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows", false);

Change it to:

pref("dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows", true);

2.Close Mozilla browser

3.Try accessing HTML page which has window.close() code snippet

Note : If you not find "all.js" 
then go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\channel-prefs.js 
and add "pref("dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows", true);" into "channel-prefs.js" file

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me perfectly:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('','_parent','');window.close();">Close this window</a>
```