# window.close(); not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

After clicking close `button` current window is not closing in `Firefox` but its working fine in `IE`

```js
function closeWin() {
    var d=window.opener;
    try {
        var param="";
        var winHref=d.document.location.href;
        if(winHref.indexOf("?") > -1){
         param=winHref.substr(winHref.indexOf("?"));
        }
        //d.document.location.href=d.document.forms[0].thankyouurl.value+'?'+param;
        d.document.location.href=d.document.getElementsByName('thankyouurl')[0].value+'?'+param;
    }
    catch(e){}
    finally{}
    window.close();
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="Button" value="Close" onClick="return closeWin();">
```

Comment: what error are you getting in the console - I'm guessing `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.close(), self.close() not working on mozilla firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465191/window-close-self-close-not-working-on-mozilla-firefox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't close the page with window.close() in Firefox unless it is opened by a script. So you'll have to trick Firefox in thinking you opened it with a script. This would work:

```
function closeWindow() { 
  window.open('','_parent',''); 
  window.close(); 
}
```

Now just call the closeWindow() whenever you want the window to close. This works in other browsers too.

Comment: Tried. It does not work in FireFox. Anyone tried this? Any other solution/worksround?

Comment: @user761100 This works when the page is in a new tab/window and the URL hasn't changed in that tab before the function is called. 
Otherwise it won't.