# browser current window close using java server side after click on alert

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to close the window after user click on alert.Here window.close() is not working

```
 String response = "<script type='text/javascript'>
 alert('You already have updated  version');window.close();            </script>";
          t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
          OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
          os.write(response.getBytes());
          os.close();
```

Comment: It because you are closing window before your console,log either place your window.close at last or use onbeforeunload  of window event to do anything before window closes

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465191/window-close-self-close-not-working-on-mozilla-firefox  try: window.open('','_parent','');window.close();

Comment: @NishanthMatha i tried ur syntax,but it is not working

Comment: @VinodLouis can you please give me syntax according to my code

Comment: which browser you'rre using

Comment: @NishanthMatha i have tried it on chrome and mozilla

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`my_window= window.open(window.location.href,"_self");my_window.close();`

Or:

`my_window= window.open("http://YOUR_SITE_URL","_self");my_window.close();`

Comment: thanks for the quick response. But i have only one page in my application and i am giving the url in ur syntax. I redirected on the same page and i stuck in infinite request loop. I have to forcefully close the browser.